# Determine whether the system can be stabilized by the control law

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, homework, state-space

I have a controls homework question I am having trouble figuring out where to start. The questions is Determine whether the system can be stabilized by the control law \$u =  - {G_1}{x_1} - {G_2}{x_2}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamyDaiabg2
% da9iabgkHiTiaadEeadaWgaaWcbaGaaGymaaqabaGccaWG4bWaaSba
% aSqaaiaaigdaaeqaaOGaeyOeI0Iaam4ramaaBaaaleaacaaIYaaabe
% aakiaadIhadaWgaaWcbaGaaGOmaaqabaaaaa!411F!
\$.

The system is \$A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&{ - 4}&{ - 4}&0\\0&{56}&{16}&0\end{array}} \right);B = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}0\\0\\1\\{ - 4}\end{array}} \right);C = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}1&1&0&0\end{array}} \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamyqaiabg2
% da9maabmaabaqbaeqabqabaaaaaeaacaaIWaaabaGaaGimaaqaaiaa
% igdaaeaacaaIWaaabaGaaGimaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacaaIWaaabaGaaG
% ymaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacqGHsislcaaI0aaabaGaeyOeI0IaaGinaaqa
% aiaaicdaaeaacaaIWaaabaGaaGynaiaaiAdaaeaacaaIXaGaaGOnaa
% qaaiaaicdaaaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaGaai4oaiaadkeacqGH9aqpdaqa
% daqaauaabeqaeeaaaaqaaiaaicdaaeaacaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqaai
% abgkHiTiaaisdaaaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaGaai4oaiaadoeacqGH9aqp
% daqadaqaauaabeqabqaaaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaIXaaabaGaaGimaa
% qaaiaaicdaaaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaaaaa!5787!
\$

My question is how exactly do I test to see if only feeding back two states yields a stabilizable system? From what I can understand, it is possible to see whether a system is fully controllable to imply that it is stabilizable. But how can one see which states are stabilizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by computing the closed-loop system. Then compute the characteristic polynomial of the closed-loop system. Finally use the Routh-Hurwitz criterion to see under what conditions of \$G_1\$ and \$G_2\$ the characteristic polynomial will be stable. If no such conditions exist the system cannot be stabilized by the proposed control law.

I did the computations of these using Mathematica and got that the system cannot be stabilized. I will summarize the results, and attach the full computations as a screen shot.

The state matrix of the closed-loop system

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -G_1 & -G_2-4 & -4 & 0 \\
 4 G_1 & 4 G_2+56 & 16 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The characteristic polynomial
$$
s^4+4 s^3+(G_1-4 G_2 -56) s^2-160 s-40 G_1
$$

The first column of the Routh table
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 4 \\
 4 G_1-16 G_2-64 \\
 16 \left(160 G_2+640\right) \\
 16 \left(-6400 G_2 G_1-25600 G_1\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

There exists no conditions under which all of the last three elements are positive.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you! I will need some time to digest this.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, I realized that we need not go through the trouble of doing the complete Routh analysis. The coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are not all positive, whatever the values of \$G_1\$ and \$G_2\$.

Comment: I am placing your answer as the best one. Thank you again! In case you are interested, I have another controls problem. I got about 75% of it. Problem is that I do not know how to handle exogenous inputs: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/288441/how-to-handle-exogenous-inputs-in-state-space-transfer-function-and-control-law